# How I can organize four absolute div with z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 absolute div, and I need to make this structure with z-index :

```
- div3 above div1 and div2  
- div4 above div3 but bellow div1 and div2.
```

This is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lu8zr2ca/10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want C > A and C > B then D > C and D < A and D < B? logically and mathematically and visually and .. it's impossible

Comment: Obviously div4 is the culprit, you should split it into two parts, e.g. use two elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes logically is impossible, and I can't split the div because the fomat is not a rectangular, I have update the fiddle with a real case : https://jsfiddle.net/Lu8zr2ca/10/

Zone 3 is good, but for zone 4 must be above the the yellow image and bellow the red zone, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Div 3 is on top of Div 1&2, so if Div 4 is on top of Div 3, it must be above Div 1&2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how solve this case : https://jsfiddle.net/Lu8zr2ca/10/  ?

Comment: @egmine Try asking it in another post. If my post answered your original question, please click the check on the left side of it.

Comment: The new jsfiddle for the same issue just with a real case  jsfiddle.net/Lu8zr2ca/10